# Email person based on people picker result

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Im trying to make a workflow that sends an email to a person chosen a people/group picker field in an InfoPath form that is submitted to a library.

The form is submitted by one person, with the intention of sending an email to another person chosen in the people/picker to authorize the submitted form.

However when in SharePoint designer, I am unable to select this field to send the email to.  Is there another way that I can extract the email address from the people picker group and display it so that it can be used to send the desired email?

Thanks

Comment: So you mean to say that, When ever you submit a Infopath form to library the workflow should pick the person from the (Here i need clarity) Group you want to send email to multiple people or to one person who is selected at that field.

Comment: Yes, when the form is submitted to the library there has to be a person entered into the filed within the form.  This is then shown in a column in the SharePoint library with the intention of the email address getting picked up from here

Comment: i was thinking either add a field into the InfoPath form using a rule to set this field from the people picker value (im struggling with this at the moment) or a way using SP.  Im a bit new and frustrated with it at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workflow that i used to get the email[image]

- Do change start option of the workflow

  1. Start workflow automatically when an item is created
     (This allows you to get email when an infopath form is submitted)

I hope this would work for you

Comment: sorry, that wouldn't work
the people picker group selects a person (not the creator) that the form will get emailed to then the new person will authorize the form.  I should have clarified this earlier

Comment: ok Re-frame your question so that i can understand that clearly